# How to set caption number to left

Tags: captions

I have caption setup:

```
\captionsetup*[figure]{labelsep=period, name=pav}
```

results look like:

[image]

I want to have the numberleft:
"4 pav. Grafinės sąsajos prototimas."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption} %

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{swap}{#2~#1}

\begin{document}%

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{labelformat=swap, name = pav, labelsep = period}
  \caption{The Larch}
  \centering%
  \includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{TheLarch}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]